# Javascript on Change not Triggering Function

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following Javascript Function:

```
function showRSS(str, year, month, day) {
    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "domain.com/script.php?days=" + str + "&year=" + year + "&month=" + month + "&day=" + day, true);

    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And the following Selection fields (dropdowns), but when the value is changed within them, the function is not being triggered:

```
<div id="calendar-container">

<input type="text" onchange="checkAge( this );" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" alt="Test" value="" onkeyup="showRSS(this.value, document.getElementById('yearSel').value, document.getElementById('monthSel').value, document.getElementById('daySel').value)" name="nights" id="field2">

    <select id="monthSel" name="monthSel"
    onchange="showRSS(document.getElementById('field2').value, document.getElementById('yearSel').value, document.getElementById('monthSel').value, document.getElementById('daySel').value)">
        <option value="0">January</option>
        <option value="1">February</option>
        <option value="2">March</option>
        <option value="3">April</option>
    </select>
    <select id="daySel" name="daySel" 
    onchange="showRSS(document.getElementById('field2').value, document.getElementById('yearSel').value, document.getElementById('monthSel').value, document.getElementById('daySel').value)">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Anyone got a solution as to why the function is not being triggered?

Comment: I suspect you get a JavaScript error, could you install Firebug in Firefox then open your page and hit F12. See what's in the console?

Comment: what are the errors. see it on developers tool, on console mood

Comment: Jack I also have field 2 - included in the edit

Comment: document.getElementById() function will work only inside script. You should declare this in the showRSS() method.

Comment: @GMR That's complete BS. Try http://jsfiddle.net/AcVQg/

Comment: @JohnSmith sorry but I still can't see field2 in your posted html code or see it added anywhere in your JavaScript code. GMR might be wrong as in that the script can work but it's not very pretty this way. You could try to use jQuery and jQueryui as that has a nice popup calendar that'll work on any browser.

Comment: @HMR see line 2 of the second code snippet please.